# Error during installation of python: /usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.26: undefined symbol: GEOSMakeValid_r

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, qgis, dpkg

on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, when trying to install `python3-venv` or trying to uninstall `python3.8`, I recieve the following error which begins at the following line:

```
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.26: undefined symbol: GEOSMakeValid_r
```

Does anyone could help me fix this? What might have went wrong?
Thanks in advance!

```
❯ sudo apt-get install python3-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-venv is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up qgis-providers (3.10.12+dfsg-1~bionic1) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.26: undefined symbol: GEOSMakeValid_r
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 installed qgis-providers package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 3.10.12+dfsg-1~bionic1); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-qgis:
 python3-qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 3.10.12+dfsg-1~bionic1); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package python3-qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 3.10.12+dfsg-1~bionic1); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                  Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 python3-qgis
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and error message when trying to install qgis on ubuntu 18.04.

Following a hint in this discussion https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2214 it seems the problem is that gdal expects geos-3.8.0 or newer while, on my system, geos-3.5.0 was installed.

Manually installing geos-3.8.1 from source (found here: https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) solved the issue and allowed me to install qgis.